# Null is passed to autowired service even after mocking - SpringBootTest

Tags: spring-boot, junit, mocking, mockito, spring-boot-test

I wanted to do integration testing of my API.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1")
public class TestController {

    @Autowired
    TestService testService;

    @RequestMapping("/welcome")
    public String welcomeMessage(@RequestParam("name") String name) {
        return testService.welcomeMessage(name);
    }
}
```

Below are the service interface and its implementation:

```
public interface TestService {
    public String welcomeMessage(String name);
}

public class TestServiceImpl implements TestService{
    @Autowired
    TestRepository repo;

    @Override
    public String welcomeMessage(String name) {
        repo.save(new StringEntity(name));
        return "Hello "+name;
    }
}
```

Below is the Test Case:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class MockitoTestingApplicationTests {

    @Autowired
    MockMvc mvc;

    @MockBean
    TestService testService;

    @MockBean
    TestController testController;

    @Test
    public void contextLoads() throws Exception {
        Mockito.when(testController.welcomeMessage(ArgumentMatchers.anyString())).thenCallRealMethod();
        Mockito.when(testService.welcomeMessage(ArgumentMatchers.anyString())).thenCallRealMethod();

        mvc.perform(get("/api/v1/welcome").param("name", "dude")).andExpect(status().isOk());
    }

}
```

I have a few questions.

1. when I'm executing the above code it is throwing an error saying cannot call real method on abstract methods. And When I'm mocking the `TestServiceImpl`, It is throwing `NullPointerException` in the Controller because the `TestService` is null. How should I fix that?
2. How should I mock the repository layer when we are using MongoDB. when I try to Mock `MongoTemplate`, It is throwing an error saying `MongoConvertor must not be null`
3. Is this the right way to write test cases. can we have code coverage without using `thenCallRealMethod()`?

Please suggest me how to proceed. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have an implementation of the service i.e. `TestServiceImpl` annotated with `@Service` (or `@Component` if it is not strictly a service)  and use spying instead of mocking:

```
@SpyBean
TestService testService;
```

Spying by default call real methods so you have to mock these that implementation you do not want to call.

Regarding repositories, you should mock the components annotated with `@Repository`, not the actual `SessionFactory` / `Template` etc. that are used within.

Comment: If I use `@SpyBean` on Controller and remove mocking of TestService, it is throwing `NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.example.demo.TestService' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate`

Comment: Why did you remove MockBean from TestService? Anyway.. in that case normal bean should be used.. maybe there is no implementation in your app?

Comment: Ok, looking closer at it you should not mock / spy the Controller at all.. you should use @SpyBean on the Service. In my opinion..

Comment: Add @Service to TestServiceImpl class. That should work.

Comment: Thank you @Maciej Kowalski. You are right. I have to use @SpyBean. But it should be used on `TestServiceImpl testService` instead of `TestService` because otherwise `org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.example.demo.TestService]: Specified class is an interface` is thrown. I know this is small and silly but it might help someone else like me if you update the answer. I will mark it as accepted.

Comment: @GaneshHoolageri Yes. Thanks for that. If the `TestServiceImpl` is annotated with `@Service` and using `@SpyBean` on `TestService` it is working fine. It should be either the above comment or this one.